# Highlighting sectors of Venn diagram in Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, set, venn-diagram

I am trying to create a program that would highlight a part of the Venn diagram, depending on user's input. The user would input a set operation and it would highlight the section. Currently, I am using Matplot lib in python but seems there is no actual way how to reference each section and change the visuals of it. Such as (the labels inside the diagrams are non-relevant):

Highlight *B-A*

[image]

Is it possible to do this in Matplot lib or any other library?
Thanks!

Comment: You could try [shapely](https://pypi.org/project/Shapely/) to calculate the appropriate regions.

Answer (score 2):

so with matplotlib you can use a second library that wraps matplotlib. If this isn't exactly what you are looking for, I suggest looking at the library's github to see how they actually make the matplotlib color change.

```
pip install matplotlib-venn

#Import libraries
from matplotlib_venn import venn2, venn2_circles, venn2_unweighted
from matplotlib_venn import venn3, venn3_circles
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt


venn2(subsets = (30, 10, 5), set_labels = ('Group A', 'Group B'))

venn2(subsets = (30, 10, 5), set_labels = ('Group A', 'Group B'), set_colors=('purple', 'skyblue'), alpha = 0.7);
```

The resources for this are found here:

https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-create-and-customize-venn-diagrams-in-python-263555527305

https://github.com/konstantint/matplotlib-venn